# How to get the field value from a parent to child relationship in apex:repeat

Tags: soql, relationships

I have a SOQL in a controller

```
 List<Application__C> response = [SELECT Contract_Number__c,
                       Name,
                       Applicant_Name__c,
                       Broker_Account__r.Name,
                       State__c,
                       Status__c, (SELECT Envelope_Status__c FROM Docusign_Histories__r ) 
                       FROM application__c WHERE CreatedDate >= :fromDate AND CreatedDate <= :toDate];
```

I want to loop through in this list and print in a visualforce page.
My Approach is

```
                    <apex:repeat value="{!response}" var="record" id="theRepeat">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="rowData">{!record.Name}</td>
                                <td class="rowData">{!record.Applicant_Name__c}</td>
                                <td class="rowData">{!record.Contract_Number__c}</td>
                                <td class="rowData">{!record.Broker_Account__r.Name}</td>
                                <td class="rowData">{!record.State__c}</td>
                                <td class="rowData">{!record.Status__c}</td>
                                <td class="rowData">{!record.Docusign_Histories__r.Envelope_Status__c}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </apex:repeat>
```

But it is throwing the following error in VF page

> Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Envelope_Status__c'

How to get the field value of parent to child relationship ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will return the parent records along with their respective child record(s). In order to display child record(s) which will be returned in a `List<sObject>`, you either have to use another `<apex:repeat>` inside that repeat tag or use index of list to display specific child record.

Using `<apex:repeat>`

```
<apex:repeat value="{!response}" var="record" id="theRepeat">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="rowData">{!record.Name}</td>
            <td class="rowData">{!record.Applicant_Name__c}</td>
            <td class="rowData">{!record.Contract_Number__c}</td>
            <td class="rowData">{!record.Broker_Account__r.Name}</td>
            <td class="rowData">{!record.State__c}</td>
            <td class="rowData">{!record.Status__c}</td>
            <apex:repeat value="{!record.Docusign_Histories__r}" var="childrecord" id="childRepeat">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="rowData">{!childrecord.Envelope_Status__c}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</apex:repeat>
```

Using index to display single record's field value

```
<apex:repeat value="{!response}" var="record" id="theRepeat">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="rowData">{!record.Name}</td>
            <td class="rowData">{!record.Applicant_Name__c}</td>
            <td class="rowData">{!record.Contract_Number__c}</td>
            <td class="rowData">{!record.Broker_Account__r.Name}</td>
            <td class="rowData">{!record.State__c}</td>
            <td class="rowData">{!record.Status__c}</td>
            <td class="rowData">{!record.Docusign_Histories__r[0].Envelope_Status__c}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works! One more thing, I always want to return only one row from the child. Can I apply a filter in the subquery?

Comment: @NoorAShuvo Yup, you can either apply a filter or can use `LIMIT 1`